# Difference between `evil-search-forward` and `evil-ex-search-forward`

Tags: evil, search

It's in the title:

**What's the difference between `evil-search-forward` and `evil-ex-search-forward`?**

When would I want to use one instead of the other?

> **`evil-search-forward`**
>   Search forward for user-entered text.
>   Searches for regular expression if `evil-regexp-search` is t.

> **`evil-ex-search-forward`**
>   Starts a forward search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`evil` has two search implementations, one is its own, the other one is a wrapper around emacs `isearch`. `evil-search-forward` wraps `isearch-forward`, `evil-ex-search-forward` invokes the internal search.

Which one is used is governed by the variable `evil-search-module`, the default is `isearch`. In this mode, `evil`'s search behaves exactly like emacs' (because it is.) When set to `evil-search` you get the behavior much more similar to `vim`. (I can't enumerate the differences since I migrated from `vim` to `emacs`/`evil` quite some time ago, but play with this variable, you will get the taste of it and decide what you like more. I use `isearch` because I get consistent behavior with other places in emacs where I stick to emacs mode and `evil` does a very good job wrapping native `isearch` and preserving `vim`-like functionality, but it's a matter of taste and habits)